# Logistic regression sample size calculation and 10:1 rule of thumb

Tags: regression, logistic, sample-size, predictor

I need to calculate the sample size for a proposed logistic regression. For the dependent variable, outcome is coded as disease or no disease. The major predictor is a continuous variable. There are 10 potential covariates but some might be removed after model fitting, due to not being statistically significant or clinically irrelevant.

I read the other posts here. These are the possible ways. Say prevalence of disease = $0.2$, then the following methods could be used:

1. Use the general rule of thumb (e.g. Peduzzi, 1996), number of events = $10 * 10 / (0.2) = 500$. How about the number of non events? That's needed to calculate the total sample size. Should I use $500 \times 2$, $500/0.2$, or ...? However, in reality, it might be impossible to recruit that many people. A way I can think of is to reduce the number of predictors.
2. Other general rules like $1:10$, $1:15$, $1:20$ exist. In any case, these rules will produce a much smaller number of events than option 1. Even if I use $1:20$, this gives me $10*20 = 200$, which is half of option 1.
3. (Hsieh, 1998) makes use of the odds ratio of the major predictor, plus the multiple correlation coefficient. Unfortunately, we don't have this info. We can only guess.

From a budget perspective, Option 2 needs much fewer people than Option 1. Do people often prefer Option 2? Is there a big difference between Option 3 and the others? Is one superior than the other? If I don't take the covariates into account for calculating sample size, but I adjust these potential confounders in the analysis, will there be a problem?

Comment: I like to look at the confidence interval for a binomial proportion. So like what is the worst true rate that could pretend it was your prevalence given your sample size. I try to pick some thing that keeps me from deceiving myself. that’s job one.

Comment: It would be helpful to give full references for Hsieh and Peduzzi, and links to whatever other posts you're basing your question on ...

Answer (score 8):

If you know enough about the target effect size<sup>*</sup> and the magnitudes and correlations of the covariates, then you can do a formal power analysis, or use a rule of thumb based on power analysis calculations (i.e., rule #3). That's better, *if you can get/are willing to make assumptions about that information*. **All** rules of thumb about sample size and power analysis are based on informed guesses.

Rule #2 is inappropriate for binary outcomes; you shouldn't use it.

Rules like #1 are based on *typical* effect sizes for a particular field (e.g., clinical medicine). The rule that Harrell (2015) gives, which is similar to Peduzzi's, is that a reasonable number of covariates is

$$
\frac{\min(\textrm{# of events}, \textrm{# of non-events})}{(10\textrm{ to } 20)}
$$

Converting this to a form where you compute required total number of observations from the number of covariates ($C$) and the prevalence ($p$), assuming $p<0.5$, and using a divisor $D$ (listed as "10 to 20" in the formula above):

$$
C = \frac{p N}{D} \quad \to \quad N = \frac{D C}{p}
$$

with $D=10$, this recovers Peduzzi's rule. 500 would be the total number of observations to plan for, not the number of events.

- in typical studies "# of events" is the smaller value (i.e. prevalence < 0.5)
- in this formulation (where you predict number of covariates from sample size, not sample size from number of covariates), the number of non-events doesn't matter
- for proper inference, doing data-based selection/dropping of covariates (specifically, model selection *based on the response variable* — you could e.g. decide to drop covariates with relatively little variability, or a covariate that was strongly correlated with another covariate) doesn't help you

Harrell (2015) chapter 4 has a lot of useful information about what your choices are when you have too many covariates and not enough observations ...

> if I don't take the covariates into account for calculating sample size, but I will adjust these potential confounders in the analysis, will there be a problem?

I think so.  However, Vittinghoff and McCulloch (2007) say:

> If we (somewhat subjectively) regard confidence interval coverage less than 93 percent, type I error greater than 7 percent, or relative bias greater than 15 percent as problematic, our results indicate that problems are fairly frequent with 2–4 EPV, uncommon with 5–9 EPV, and still observed with 10–16 EPV

(EPV == "events per variable"; this is the same as $D$ above because the number of events $pN = DC$ ... so you might get away with (say) $D=7$ or as small as 5 ...)

---

<sup>*</sup> Target effect size is a delicate subject; you shouldn't design a study based on the *expected* magnitude of the effect, but on the *minimum* biological/subject-area-related effect of interest, i.e. the magnitude such that effects smaller than that can be considered biologically (or whatever) unimportant ...

---

Harrell Jr., Frank E. 2015. Regression Modeling Strategies: With Applications to Linear Models, Logistic and Ordinal Regression, and Survival Analysis. 2nd ed. 2015 edition. Cham: Springer.

Vittinghoff, Eric, and Charles E. McCulloch. 2007. “Relaxing the Rule of Ten Events per Variable in Logistic and Cox Regression.” American Journal of Epidemiology 165 (6): 710–18. https://doi.org/10.1093/aje/kwk052.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your detailed explanation. For Harrell's book, I want to confirm if you are talking about this book https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-19425-7. Chapter 3 is for missing data, imputation etc.

Comment: sorry, I meant chapter 4.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

It has been shown that the rough rules of thumb such as the number of events divided by 15 rule do not work well enough.  This is for multiple reasons including the fact that you need 96 observations just to estimate the intercept by itself, and the needed sample size goes down as $R^{2} \uparrow$.  The most accurate and comprehensive approach is by [Riley et al](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.7992) for which an R package exists.